# telegram bot keyboard on chat field

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to click a button and have text shown in a chat field and not directly on the chat screen?

For example:

- There is some buttons keyboard [1] [2] [3]
- When I press on [1] button then `1` is shown on chat field, not on chat screen
- When I click [3][2][1] then on chat field will be shown `321`
- When I press `<enter>` `321` is show on the screen.

**Question**

Is this possible on telegram bot?

```
 bot.on('ask.no', msg => {
  let markup = bot.keyboard([
     ['9', '8','7','*'],
     ['6', '5','4','/'],
     ['3', '2','1','+'],
     ['.', '0','=','-'],
   ], { resize: true });
  return bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, 'please input key or number', { markup});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As official [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards) says:

> Tapping any of the buttons will immediately send the respective command.

No. You can't delay showing button values on chat screen.